# Skip Batch in While Loop if 60 seconds elapsed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use a WHILE loop to iterate through batches to match a Customer Reference to a data table. The SQL Query I produced gets the desired results so I'm looking to run this over a longer time period - hense the while loop and batches.

The batches take roughly 2 seconds to insert another 10,000 rows into the table, the issue I am encountering means that with specific batches the process continues to run but with no inserts taking place. I have identified that this seems to be consistently down to specific Call_IDs in the batch where no inserts happen, but when run for the problematic record specifically that will insert.

I am looking for a solution that will allow the process to run the INSERT INTO in the batches of 10,000 records, but will skip a batch if it takes longer than 10 seconds. I have tried to SET LOCK_TIMEOUT = 60000 but this doesn't seem to change anything which hints the issue is not lock related.

I then plan on running the process for the skipped batches but with a much smaller increment so I can identify the records that cause the issues.

FYI I'm dealing with roughly 4 million records.

Thanks in Advance!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.USR_FN_CRM_AGREEMENTS_BATCHES
AS

DECLARE @BatchStart  INT;
DECLARE @ResultCount INT;
DECLARE @Increment   INT;
DECLARE @BatchStartTime DATETIME;

SET @Increment = 10000;
SET @BatchStart = 2858110;
SET @ResultCount = 1;
SET @BatchStartTime = GETDATE()

WHILE(@ResultCount > 0)
    BEGIN

    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 60000;


        WITH AccountReferences
             AS (SELECT ra.ID AS AccountReference, 
                        ra.MainAsset, 
                        cgct.Contact_ID, 
                        cgct.Group_Contact_ID, 
                        ra.AccountStartDate, 
                        ra.AccountEndDate
                 FROM SQLActiveH_Reporting.dbo.Contact_Group_Contacts_T cgct
                      LEFT JOIN SQLActiveH_Reporting.dbo.Rent_Accounts ra ON cgct.Group_ID = ra.ContactDatabaseReference
                ),
             CRM_Calls
             AS (SELECT cct.Call_ID, 
                        cct.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID, 
                        cct.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID, 
                        cct.Call_Relates_To_Asset_ID AS Asset_ID, 
                        cct.Entered_Actual_DT AS Call_Date_Time
                 FROM SQLActiveH_Reporting.dbo.CRM_Calls_T cct
                 WHERE cct.Call_ID > @BatchStart
                       AND cct.Call_ID <= @BatchStart + @Increment
                       AND cct.Call_ID NOT IN (2873237)
             ),
             DataPrep
             AS (
             SELECT CASE WHEN AR1.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR1.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR2.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR2.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR3.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR3.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR4.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR4.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR5.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR5.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR6.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR6.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR7.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR7.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR8.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR8.AccountReference
                             WHEN AR9.AccountReference IS NOT NULL THEN AR9.AccountReference
                             ELSE NULL
                        END AS AccountReference, 
                        CRM.Call_ID, 
                        CRM.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID, 
                        CRM.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID, 
                        CRM.Asset_ID, 
                        CRM.Call_Date_Time, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CRM.Call_ID ORDER BY CRM.Call_Date_Time) AS SEQ
                 FROM CRM_Calls CRM
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR1 ON CRM.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID = AR1.Group_Contact_ID AND CRM.Asset_ID = AR1.MainAsset
                                                         AND CRM.Call_Date_Time BETWEEN AR1.AccountStartDate AND AR1.AccountEndDate
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR2 ON CRM.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID = AR2.Group_Contact_ID
                                                         AND CRM.Call_Date_Time BETWEEN AR2.AccountStartDate AND AR2.AccountEndDate
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR3 ON CRM.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID = AR3.Group_Contact_ID
                                                         AND CRM.Asset_ID = AR3.MainAsset
                                                         AND CRM.Call_Date_Time BETWEEN AR3.AccountStartDate AND AR3.AccountEndDate
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR4 ON CRM.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID = AR4.Group_Contact_ID
                                                         AND CRM.Call_Date_Time BETWEEN AR4.AccountStartDate AND AR4.AccountEndDate
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR5 ON CRM.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID = AR5.Group_Contact_ID
                                                         AND CRM.Asset_ID = AR5.MainAsset
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR6 ON CRM.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID = AR6.Group_Contact_ID
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR7 ON CRM.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID = AR7.Group_Contact_ID
                                                         AND CRM.Asset_ID = AR7.MainAsset
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR8 ON CRM.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID = AR8.Group_Contact_ID
                      LEFT JOIN AccountReferences AR9 ON CRM.Asset_ID = AR9.MainAsset
                                                         AND CRM.Call_Date_Time BETWEEN AR9.AccountStartDate AND AR9.AccountEndDate
                       )
             INSERT INTO Admin_DBA.dbo.CRM_Accounts
                    SELECT dp.AccountReference, 
                           dp.Call_ID, 
                           dp.Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID, 
                           dp.Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID, 
                           dp.Asset_ID, 
                           dp.Call_Date_Time,
                           @BatchStart
                    FROM DataPrep dp
                    WHERE Seq = 1
                 ;


        SET @BatchStart = @BatchStart + @Increment;
        SET @ResultCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    END;

USE [Admin_DBA]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CRM_Accounts]    Script Date: 18/07/2019 
09:21:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CRM_Accounts](
    [AccountReference] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Call_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Call_Made_By_Group_Contact_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Call_Relates_To_Group_Contact_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Asset_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Call_Date_Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SEQ] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: This can't (comfortably) be done from T-SQL, because there is no way to include a timeout for an individual command. About the only avenue is creating a resource governor pool, but even then getting it to execute on that resource pool practically requires running it from an Agent job, as you can't explicitly create new connections in T-SQL either. If you need a stable, traceable solution for this sort of thing, client code (whether SSIS, PowerShell or a programming language of your choice) is a better bet, at least for the part of controlling the batches and recovering from errors.

Comment: @dlatikay Due to the fact one Call_ID could potentially match all 9 join criteria the WHERE Seq = 1 is there to only commit one of these matches to the output table. I tested the divide and conquer approach but when I isolated to one record and ran that individually (insert into outside of batch) it loaded to the table fine. I did try to run and manually identify but the next failure after the first occurred only 5k rows later, given the 4m to process that could be a lot of manual divide and conquering!

Comment: @JeroenMostert As there is no error being thrown due to the record just hanging I’m not sure that error handling in SSIS or other tools would be useful. That being said I’ll explore this option tomorrow and feedback

Comment: @dlatikay Added the CREATE TABLE script for the CRM_Accounts table. No Ignore Dup Key or other constraints used.

Comment: @dlatikay 
Because it isn't actually inserting that row, it's getting to it and stopping it feels like a table lock, but as you can see I have the LOCK TIMEOUT set. It's not passing that batch as a 0 insert it's just stopping at the batch with a record it doesn't like and not proceeding to insert (as if stuck on the select)

Comment: @dlatikay Full Create Table Statement added

Comment: are we in a concurrent scenario? can you put the database in single-user mode? consider also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125712/114522

Comment: @dlatikay Tried to create a new database 'NF_TEST' and set the database to single-user mode. Imported the source tables, destination table and stored procedure to the database. Set the isolation level to snapshot and allowed snapshot isolation at database level. Left query to run for 5 minutes and terminated. Froze on third batch as per previous runs... 
Going to try via SSIS package

Comment: Printed @@ResultCount and @@RowCount and after the first two batches and it printed 1 and 0 respectively. Subsequently printed the @@BatchStart variable and can see that this is iterating by 10000 rows between the first two batches.